# F#: Want to reinitialize enumerator

Tags: f#, ienumerable

I have a sequence of prime number divisors that I want to iterate over for each prime candidate.  I use GetEnumerator() MoveNext() and Current.  I can't reinitialize the enumerator to start from the beginning.  I tried Reset(), which compiled, but gives a runtime error of not implemented.

I am using  F# 2.0 Interactive build 4.0.40219.1

Any suggestions?

Regards,
Doug

---

To clarify the problem: For each prime candidate N I want to iterate thru the prime divisors sequence (up to approx sqrt N) and completely factor N or determine if it is prime. Using the GetEnumerator, MoveNext, Current approach works for the first prime candidate, but on the second prime candidate I want to iterate on my divisors sequence from the beginning.  It appears that the only way to do this is to create a new iterator (which is awkward for a large number of prime candidates) or create a new prime sequence (which I don't want to do).

The suggestion of using something like "divisors in seqPrimes" appears to exhaust all divisors before stopping, but I want to stop as soon as a prime divisor divides the prime candidate.

If there is an error in my logic in the above statements, please let me know.

I investigated Seq.cache, and this worked for me. The resulting code follows:

---

```
// Recursive isprime function (modified from MSDN)
let isPrime n =
    let rec check i =
        i > n/2 || (n % i <> 0 && check (i + 2))
    if n = 2 then true
    elif (n%2) = 0 then false
    else check 3

let seqPrimes = seq { for n in 2 .. 100000 do if isPrime n then yield n }

// Cache the sequence to avoid recomputing the sequence elements.
let cachedSeq = Seq.cache seqPrimes


// find the divisors of n (or determine prime) using the seqEnum enumerator 
let rec testPrime n (seqEnum:System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<int>) =
  if n = 1 then printfn "completely factored"
  else
    let nref = ref n
    if seqEnum.MoveNext() then
      let divisor = seqEnum.Current
      //printfn "trial divisor %A" divisor
      if divisor*divisor > n then printfn "prime %A" !nref
      else
        while ((!nref % divisor) = 0) do
          printfn "divisor %A" divisor
          nref := !nref / divisor
        testPrime !nref seqEnum

// test
for x = 1000000 to 1000010 do
  printfn "\ndivisors of %d = " x
  let seqEnum = cachedSeq.GetEnumerator()
  testPrime x seqEnum
  seqEnum.Dispose()   // not needed
```

Comment: I would find it to be extremely rare to actually need to explicitly call members on an `IEnumerator` when you could just use the `for x in y` syntax. If you need to; just create a new enumerator. Posting your code would be helpful because I think we can find a better alternative.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example demonstrating the error?

Comment: Have you tried to use Seq.cache ?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean that the cause of your attempt to reset the Enumerator is the high cost of regenerating your sequence of primes you may consider [**caching**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370430.aspx) your sequence. This manner of using your sequence would be idiomatic to F#. To show you how to do this I refer you to the following snippet taken from [this context](http://infsharpmajor.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/project-euler-problem-10/):

```
let rec primes = 
    Seq.cache <| seq { yield 2; yield! Seq.unfold nextPrime 3 }
and nextPrime n =
    if isPrime n then Some(n, n + 2) else nextPrime(n + 2)
and isPrime n =
    if n >= 2 then
        primes 
        |> Seq.tryFind (fun x -> n % x = 0 || x * x > n)
        |> fun x -> x.Value * x.Value > n
    else false
```

You may play with this snippet to see that the penalty of re-enumeration here gets negligible.

Talking of `Reset()` method of `IEnumerator`, I recall that it is not implemented in current F#, i.e. throws `System.NotSupportedException`. See [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.reset.aspx#Y0) for justification.

**ADDITION:**
In order to test it with the test you've suggested below:

```
for x in [1000000..1000010] do
    printfn "\ndivisors of %d" x
    primes
    |> Seq.takeWhile ((>) (int(sqrt(float x))))
    |> Seq.iter (fun n -> if x%n = 0 then printf "%d " n)
```

On my laptop test execution takes mere 3ms.

Comment: Thanks for all of the comments. It appears that to reset the enumerator (so it starts from the beginning of a sequence) you have to create a new enumerator (which seems awkward for testing a large number of prime number candidates) or create a new sequence (which I don't want to do).

Comment: I used the "Answer Your Question" and sent it, but it has not appeared yet.

Comment: @DougT: That is right, resetting an enumerator is equivalent to creating a new enumerator; the latter is normal and idiomatic in F#. Using a cashed sequence would allow you to pay no performance penalty for this course of actions. You may play with the code above in `fsi` to see for yourself.

Comment: Gene:  Thanks for your help.  -- Doug